# ZF2 Session not lasting on redirect

Tags: session, redirect, zend-framework2

My site uses multiple languages and my users can click on flags to set their desired language. When that flag is clicked, a Session should store that information and then i want my controller to redirect the user to another page. This i do with the following code:

```
<?php
public function setLangAction () {
 $oLanguageCookie = new Container('language');
 $oLanguageCookie->lang = $this->params ('langvar');
 $this->redirect()->toRoute('loadpage', array('page' => 'home'));
}
?>
```

However, when i print_r($_SESSION) in the indexAction (the action where loadpage routes to), $_SESSION is empty.

Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 0):

Depending where you param comes from you should execute

- $this->params()->fromQuery('langvar');
- $this->params()->fromPost('langvar');

unless it is a route parameter then you can use either:

- $this->params()->fromRoute('langvar');
- $this->params('langvar');